# How to uninstall/remove a .run file?

Tags: uninstall, xampp, wordpress

So I installed the XAMPP with a .run extension by running chmod+x filename.run and it git installed. But now I want to uninstall it. How do i do so?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can uninstall a program that uses a .run installer is if it provides an uninstaller. As mentioned by Terrance you can try uninstall script by xampp